# Solr drops/deletes all old documents while reindexing

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, solrcloud

Version: **Solr 4.1**

Problem statement:

1. Solr delete/drops all the old documents when we click on the full-import od Data import handler. After the full import is complete, every thing works fine.
2. help me understand the JVM values attached as image, I am trying to connect it to the issue.

As per my understanding solr will not delete/drop the old documents till the new documents are imported fully. But in my case it drops the old documents while new documents are partially imported.

Details:

1. We are using Solr Cloud with single shard and 2 replica.
   S1-R1--------S1-R2
2. Using a amazon load balancer to balance the hit on each of them.
3. Both of the solr are attached to 3 zookepers.
4. Memory allocation: JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms8192m -Xmx12288m -XX:PermSize=3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=8192m -Xss4m"
5. The solr admin panel is showing:

   - Physical Memory 98.2%
   - Swap Space 0.0%
   - File Descriptor Count 0.2%
   - JVM-Memory 34.3%

[image: Solr Admin Panel JVM info]

Comment: What's your auto commit setting in solrconfig? Make sure you have `openSearcher` set to false. Also you need to ensure that no other client is issuing commits to Solr when your full import is running.

Comment: @arun yes, and I observed that the auto commit is have a tag with time = 1500 , I increased it to 15000000 and document to commit = 1000000. I tested it on UAT , it's working fine. I am waiting to test it on perf.

Answer (score 0):

1. Solr delete/drops all the old documents when we click on the full-import of Data import handler. After the full import is complete, every thing works fine.

-- 
As you ask clean = true,
*clean : (default 'true'). Tells whether to clean up the index before the indexing is started.*

With this DIH first issues a "delete all" update query.
Then it start adding the new documents. After its compltes/finish, the DIH issues a commit, which enforce the new documents that added and delete all the old documents which existed before the indexing started.

You can choose optimize as well but this could be expensive operation.

*optimize : (default 'true' up to Solr 3.6, 'false' afterwards). Tells whether to optimize after the operation.) 
Please note: this can be a very expensive operation and usually does not make sense for delta-imports.*

Comment: Clean was not equals to true.

Comment: I confirmed from our team. We send it false. Although I think by default it is false

Comment: check if you have added the unique key for your document..The <uniqueKey> declaration can be used to inform Solr that there is a field in your index which should be unique for all documents. If a document is added that contains the same value for this field as an existing document, the old document will be deleted....